# How to python import a specific variable from a file without getting undefined name error for other variables

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to import a certain variable from file1 into file2. I import the variable I want, but then get an error because it doesn't recognize other objects in file1. Those objects are defined elsewhere, but I don't care about them in file2.

I tried removing the other objects in file2, as a test, and it works fine. But I can't just remove that content, as other files need it.

In file1.py:

```
 var1 = 5

 object1.member1 = 4    # "object1" class instantiation created elsewhere
```

In file2.py:

```
 from file1 import var1

 var2 = var1 + 6
```

Error:

```
 File “file1.py”, line 2, in <module> object1.member1 = 4

 NameError: name ‘object1’ is not defined
```

I would expect "from fileX import varX" to only import the value of varX and not worry about the rest of fileX.

Ideal result is: var2 = 11.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If `object1` isn't defined in file1, then *no one* can import that file at all. The file simply isn't valid Python.

Comment: No it isn't. `object1` is scoped to the file1 namespace. The only way to make this work would be some horrible `exec` hack.

Answer (score 2):

I see several possibilities.

1. Refactor `file1.py` so it behaves properly when imported by *any* other module. That file is badly designed as it is now, so pay off the technical debt and program it properly.
2. Copy `file1.py` to another module, say `file1_copy.py`, them modify it to remove the problematic code. Import from the modified copy, not the original.
3. Don't import from `file1.py`. Instead, treat it as a text file. Open it as a text file and loop through the lines. When you find a line that starts with possible spaces then the text `var1` (ending in a space) or `var1=` then parse the rest of the line to get your desired value of `var1`. This depends on the line `var = 5` not being "hidden" but starting a line.
4. Again, use `file1.py` as a text file, but this time use regular expressions to find `var1 =`. This can fail but is more likely to succeed than the previous option. Of course, you need to understand regular expressions for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your file1 - at least in this reduced example - is missing an `import` for a file0 that defines `object1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this cleanly.  The problem is that your `file1` module is *not* modular: it does *not* contain an atomic, encapsulated set of features.  If your use cases include the *requirement* to use `var1` *without* `object1`, then you've violated the modular assumptions made when `file1` was created.

You need to split `file1` to serve your use model.